# How to edit files inside a docker container?

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra

I cloned the docker-sinatra from Github (https://github.com/tcnksm-sample/docker-sinatra).

Built the image using:

```
sudo docker build -t sinatra .
```

Run the container:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 4567:4567 sinatra
```

Everything works fine. Now I want to change the content of the application file inside the container. I tried to attach the container and open the application file with vi and edit it but it's kinda hectic and doesn't work.

Is there a better way to edit files inside the container or a better tool instead of vi that I can use inside the container?

Comment: have a look at `docker exec` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to permanently change the contents of the app file? Then change it before you do the docker build.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed nano in the docker container so I could use it instead of vi to change to application file.

vi is behaving weirdly when I tried to edit the application file inside the container I don't know if it just me.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker-sinatra` docker container was built from a **ubuntu** base. 
Thus when inside the container, you can install `vi/vim` by issuing command

```
sudo apt-get install vi
sudo apt-get install vim
```